# Customisation of android AppWidget launcher icon

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created a AppWidget for android with 2x1 ratio. The launcher icon of the widget is compressed in the centre. [image]

By seeing the attached screen shot we can see the WiFi widget and WorldClock are compressed into centre where as YouTube is filled its area completely. How to customise widget launcher icon ?

Answer (score 1):

Set a proper widget [preview image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#preview).